# Find Range of ASCII Characters Using An Excel Worksheet Formula

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a column of Text Strings. Some of them have ASCII Characters greater than Char(127). I'd like to have a formula in the column next to it that will search the first column for any characters either in a range of ASCII characters or greater than Char(127). If it finds one that I'd like it to simply display "found" otherwise be left blank.

Is there a formula that would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text strings start in A1, use the following formula and copy down:

```
=IF(MAX(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,LEN(A1),1)),1)))>127,"found","")
```

Validate the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as it is an array formula.